# Initializing array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, initialization

I want to initialize each element of the array through the constructor

```
    const int size=5;
Student students[size];
students[0]=("Sarah",96,92,90); <---- the error is here
```

constructor

```
Student(string sn,double m1,double m2,double fin)
{
    studentName=sn;
    midterm1Grade=m1;
    midterm2Grade=m2;
    finalExamGrade=fin;
}
```

it shows me an error with the way I am intializing

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Use a constructor initializer list (and include those other members in it).

Comment: it shows me an error with the way I am intializing

Comment: Generally we expect you to tell us what the error is, and ask us a question about it.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. C++ doesn't recognise a random parenthesised, comma-delimited list of *things*, because it doesn't know that you intend that list to be a list of arguments to the `Student` constructor.

Instead, you must create a temporary, un-named object of type `Student` and assign it:

```
const unsigned int SIZE = 5;

Student students[SIZE];
students[0] = Student("Sarah", 96, 92, 90);
//            ^^^^^^^
```

Note, though, that this is *not* initialisation. It's merely after-the-fact assignment. Because of this, your compiler will require `Student` to have a default constructor (one that takes no arguments), because it will require it for the initial creation of the `SIZE` elements, on the line `Student students[SIZE]`.

To initialise, perhaps you can do something like this:

```
Student students[] = {
   { "Sarah", 96, 92, 90 },
   { "Bob",   80, 72, 54 },
   // ...
};
```

Notice how we no longer need the constant named `SIZE`: when we initialise like this, the initialiser knows how many elements there are going to be, so the array length can be automatically determined.

You may still want to keep `SIZE` for use elsewhere, though, in which case I'd recommend putting it back into the array declaration so that if the initialiser list length is at odds with this size then you will get a pleasing compiler error.

Comment: @user3010026: Like this ^ :)

Answer (score 3):

```
    const int size=5;
Student students[size] = { { "Sarah",96,92,90 }, { /*initializer list for index 1 }, ...{ /*initializer list for index 4 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your construction happened at the line below

Student students[size]